# Count of DAX measure on static date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a matrix visual that calculates the sum for the latest day of the report and compares it to the sum of the final day of the prior year.
I am having trouble counting that measure when it meets the criteria needed. I believe the solution is to reference the final day of the year in the filtering but cannot get it to work.

The report shows the latest date, a matrix visual, and a line chart over time. The date changes as the line chart is clicked and the measures below work as intended.

**My measure for daily sum:**

```
NNDR_Sum = 

    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Report[DepositAvgCalYTDBal]),
        Report[FullDate] = MAX(Report[FullDate])
    )
```

**Final day of prior year sum:**

```
NNDR_SumPriorYear = 

VAR MaxDate = MAX(Report[FullDate])

VAR LastDayPriorYear = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX(Report[FullDate]),
        YEAR(Report[FullDate]) = YEAR(MaxDate) - 1
    )
RETURN

    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Report[DepositAvgCalYTDBal]),
        Report[FullDate] = LastDayPriorYear
        )
```

**Attempt at counting final day prior year sum:**

```
NNDR_CountPriorYear =
COUNTX (
    FILTER ( VALUES ( Report[RGNumber] ), [NNDR_SumPriorYear] >= 250000 ),
    Report[RGNumber]
)
```

The counting measure changes as the year goes on, when the intended behavior is a static line.